# Crystal Reports, calculate sum field

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I need your help, how can I know the total(sum) in a field that is itself the joining of two formulas:

**Main formula:**

```
sum(@weight)
```

**Formula 1:**

```
@open = if ({OrderRel.OurReqQty}
    - (Sum ({ShipDtl.OurInventoryShipQty}, {OrderRel.OrderRelNum}))
    - (Sum({ShipDtl.OurJobShipQty}, {OrderRel.OrderRelNum}))) < 0 then 0
else
    {OrderRel.OurReqQty}
    - (Sum ({ShipDtl.OurInventoryShipQty}, {OrderRel.OrderRelNum}))
    - (Sum({ShipDtl.OurJobShipQty}, {OrderRel.OrderRelNum}))
```

**Formula 2:**

```
@weight = {@open}*{Part.NetWeight}
```

I can't calculate the `sum` field by referring the `@open` and `@weight` formulas.

Comment: What formula you use that needs both the @weight and @open?

Comment: this one: sum(@weight)

Answer (score 0):

You can't calculate the sum by just using sum function, Instead you may use running total or write a formula to calculate sum of the weight function like sum one by one for each group and then reset it at start of the group

Comment: Can you exemplify, please?

Comment: Ok what I am trying to tell you is to sum the arithematic operation on two formulas you can try using the running total as `sum` can't be directly used in formulas. Let me know if you need further explanation on running total

Answer (score 0):

Make a third formula that uses the logic `{@open} + {@weight}`. This will get the sum of the two values *per record*.

If you're looking for a grand total of *every* instance of Open and Weight on the report, use the new formula as the field to summarize a Running Total. Set the *Type of Summary* to sum, evaluate for each record, and reset never.

Comment: Can you exemplify, please?

Comment: I cant´t understand your explanation

Comment: @xptoGirl You have 2 formulas now. Make a 3rd formula. This formula will have `{@open} + {@weight}` in it. Put this formula next to the others. That might be all you need. If you wanted a total(sum) of *all* your data, keep the formula where it is but Surpress it. Then make a *Running Total* at the bottom of your report. Tell the running total to use the new formula. ...Does that make sense?